# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

I'm getting the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < " when simply trying to include jQuery 1.9.1 in my .Net page. The code for the page is below. I have checked my jQuery 1.9.1 file and it is fine, I have other pages using that same file with no error. I have even tried using jQuery 1.10.2 and got the same error. Without the jQuery script tag I have no errors, and I am lost as to what the issue is.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="NewLogin.aspx.cs" Inherits="Platform.Account.NewLogin" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title>Merchants TotalView</title>
        <script src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                <div id="status">
                    <asp:Literal ID="litStatus" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                </div>
                <div id="login" runat="server">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblUsername" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtUsername">Username:</asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPassword" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtPassword">Password:</asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                    <br />
                    <a id="lnkForgotPass" href="NewLogin.aspx?mode=forgot">forgot password</a>
                    <a id="lnkForgotUser" href="NewLogin.aspx?mode=forgot">forgot username</a>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Submit"></asp:Button>
                </div>
                <div id="forgot" runat="server">
                    <input id="hdnForgot" runat="server" type="hidden" />
                    <asp:Literal ID="litStatusMessage" runat="server"></asp:Literal><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtEmail">Email Address:</asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnForgot" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnForgot_Click"></asp:Button>
                </div>
                <div id="change" runat="server">
                    change pass
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it giving you a line?

Comment: Have you looked at the console and look to see what it says the script file is. I am willing to bet it is serving up HTML 404 error page and not the script.

Comment: Did you check if the file `scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js` is accessible *within the browser*? It might render an error page (html), thereby the error.

Comment: Does it happen when you add it directly from jQuery site,the global link provided in demo examples?

Comment: The console is saying line 3 of the file, both with 1.9.1 and 1.10.2.

The file is accessible within the browser.

I just tried using the CDN and that actually works just fine for some reason. However we've been asked not to use CDN for the scripts so I can't use that as a permanent solution. It does kind of prove that there is something wrong with the local copy.

Comment: go to CDN Link...Copy and paste it on your local drive and reference that file in your project and see if that works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the `runat="server"` from the head tag

```
<head>
    <title>Merchants TotalView</title>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: @CoreyT did you try this? I think it's something to do with .net trying to load the script as an C#/VB script.